# Symlink to ~/Desktop or other system files not working in OSX Sierra

Tags: macos, finder

Prior to OSX Sierra, having symlinks pointing system-related folders to other in a different place, worked flawlessly (moving Desktop folder from OS's SSD drive to a HDD with bigger capacity, for example).

Now with OSX Sierra if you try to do this with Desktop, icons just don't appear and trying to create a new folder, throws a system error.

Does anybody know if it's possible to achieve? I know it's a beta system and unstable.